# Background na tag aside esconde todo conteúdo dentro da tag

Tags: html5, css3

Olá, nos meus estudos de css e html estou criando paginas e me deparei com um seguinte problema que estou a alguns dias tentando entender, eu tenho uma tag  e dentro dela tenho um background-image que está cobrindo todo conteúdo, por que se dar esse comportamento? e como posso resolver?

código html:

```
 <aside>
            <img src="br.jpg" alt="" width="150%">
            <p class="cc1">Already have an account?</p>
            <h1 class="cc2">Go to your account</h1>
            <input class="cc3" type="button" value="sign up">

    </aside>
```

código Css:

```
aside{
    width: 50%; height: 100%; position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0;

}
```

eu já tentei aplicar direto no css mas não obtive resultado, antecipadamente venho agradecer a quem dispor do seu tempo para me ajudar, meu muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O comportamento é óbvio, como você pode ter um aside de 50% de largura e uma imagem de 150% de largura? Claro que vai cobrir, corrija da seguinte forma:

```
 <aside>
   <img id="imagem_teste" src="br.jpg">
    <p class="cc1">Already have an account?</p>
    <h1 class="cc2">Go to your account</h1>
    <input class="cc3" type="button" value="sign up">
</aside>
```

Css:

#imagem_teste{
   width:25%;
  }

**Ou 2 forma alternativa é:**

```
<aside>
    <p class="cc1">Already have an account?</p>
    <h1 class="cc2">Go to your account</h1>
    <input class="cc3" type="button" value="sign up">
</aside>
```

**Css:**

```
aside{
 height:30%; //30% de altura irá deixar um espaço sobrando
 width:100%; preenche 100% da largura da tela
 background: url(fundo- 
 br.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
background-position: 30% 45%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```

**Obs: Pode mudar a altura e largura da img para ver qual fica melhor para ti**

Comment: olá eu quero que a imagem em questão sirva como background do aside, mas não consigo manipular a mesma para ficar ajustada corretamente dentro do aside

Comment: Editado, veja se resolve seu problema :)

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda mas mesmo assim o conteúdo continua como uma especie de padding da img e não acima dela

Comment: Tente um position: absolute; bottom:0; no css

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar a imagem não com a tag `img`, mas sim como *css*:

```
  background-image: url("br.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
```

---

```css
aside{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB0IX.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <p class="cc1">Already have an account?</p>
  <h1 class="cc2">Go to your account</h1>
  <input class="cc3" type="button" value="sign up">
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a resposta do Daniel seja a melhor neste caso, você deve usar a imagem como um background de um elemento e não colocar o elemento dentro da tag.

MAS, se precisar colocar o elemento dentro da tag tente assim:

```
<style>
    aside {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    #tg1{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;

    }
    #tg2{
        position: relative;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
</style>

<aside>
    <div id="tg1">
        <p class="cc1">Already have an account?</p>
        <h1 class="cc2">Go to your account</h1>
        <input class="cc3" type="button" value="sign up">
    </div>
    <div id="tg2">
        <img src="br.jpg" alt="" width="150%">
     </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: E minha também que fiz primeiro ~_~ mas como não sei como ele quer exatamente ... Já que todos aqui já sugeriu a fazê-lo isso e não resolveu ... Acredito que ele deve ser mais claro.